# html tags inside rows in database

Tags: database, html, jsp

I think this question has not already been asked. I have a table in the database with a column that stores text with html tags within (the `<b>` tag to be specific).

When I try to print this text in a jsp I realise that with Firefox this tag is rendered (the text appears in bold) but with IE and Chrome it isn't.

Any ideas where the problem might be?

Thanks in advance and sorry if the question has already been answered in a previous post.

Comment: How do you print the text? Using scriptlets as in <% out.print(str); %> or with JSTL <c:out> which has an attribute escapeXml set to true by default.

Comment: Can you post an example of the HTML tags you are using. To find your problem we have to start with the source, which is the HTML tags you are using to render your page.

Comment: Yes of course. In the jsp I define a variable like this:  <% String text = rs.getString("column_in_database"); %> where rs is the result of executing a SQL statement (rs = statement.executeQuery(sSQL);). This string contains <b> and <br> tags. Then I do: <% out.println(text); %>. The weird thing is that in Firefox and IE the string is rendered in bold and with the break lines, and in Chrome with the break lines BUT NOT in bold.

Comment: Sorry, in IE the string is displayed correctly (as Firefox), the problem occurs in Chrome. (I corrected the previous post). Do you need more info?

Comment: do a view source in chrome and see if `<b>` tag is appearing for the text in question. I think this might be because you might have zoomed-out resolution in chrome.

Comment: Solved, the problem was with firefox, not in Chrome. The whole text was using a font-weight:bold style defined in a css, but it seems that in Firefox if we apply this style to a text that contains <b> tags, it counts bold double. Modifying the css did the trick.

Answer (score 1):

Solved, the problem was with firefox, not in Chrome. The whole text was using a font-weight:bold style defined in a css, but it seems that in Firefox if we apply this style to a text that contains  tags, it counts bold double. Modifying the css did the trick.